# Connect-MsolService using graph access tokens failed

Tags: powershell-5.1

I usually run a modified version of the script provided by Microsoft on how to “[Convert per-user MFA enabled and enforced users to disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates#convert-per-user-mfa-enabled-and-enforced-users-to-disabled)”.

If I run it interactively, the cmdlet “[Connect-MsolService](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/msonline/connect-msolservice)” works like a charm. However, as soon as I tried to use the parameters “AdGraphAccessToken” and “MsGraphAccessToken” it throws the following errors:

> Connect-MsolService : An unexpected error occurred.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> +Connect-MsolService -AdGraphAccessToken $AadAccessToken -MsGraphAcces ...
>
> +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> +CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], MicrosoftOnlineException
>
> +FullyQualifiedErrorId :  Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.InvalidHeaderException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService
>
> Connect-MsolService : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> +Connect-MsolService -AdGraphAccessToken $AadAccessToken -MsGraphAcces ...
>
> +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> +CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], MicrosoftOnlineException
>
> +FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService

When passing the same tokens to the cmdlet “[Connect-AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread)”, it goes as expected.

I use the following snippet for acquiring the tokens:

```
$TenantId        = 'MyTenantId'
$Authority       = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token' -f $TenantId
$ClientId        = 'MyAzureActiveDirectoryAppId'
$ClientSecret    = 'MyAzureActiveDirectoryAppSecret'

$Parameters      =
@{
  Authority    = $Authority
  ClientId     = $ClientId
  ClientSecret = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force)
}

$AadAccessToken  = (Get-MsalToken @Parameters -Scopes 'https://graph.windows.net/.default').AccessToken
$MsAccessToken   = (Get-MsalToken @Parameters -Scopes 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default').AccessToken
#Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $AadAccessToken -MsAccessToken $MsAccessToken -AccountId $ClientId -TenantId $TenantId
Connect-MsolService -AdGraphAccessToken $AadAccessToken -MsGraphAccessToken $MsAccessToken -AzureEnvironment AzureCloud
```

I know that the modules [MSOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview) a [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview) have been deprecated in favor of [Microsoft.Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview), but since there is no other programmatic way to [Enable per-user MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates) I would kindly ask you people for some guidance: am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you ever get this working

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to create phoneAuthenticationMethod MFA using the MS graph which is still in beta phase:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-post-phonemethods?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell

Comment: @ MehtabSiddique, the functionality you have pointed out allows the setting of an authentication method (phone); my goal is to set the MFA to disabled, enabled or enforced.